# Sqlalchemy search with ilike doesn't work properly

Tags: sql, search, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have User model with fields `name` `surname` and etc.
And I want to search by name and surname in one query.
But if i want to search by partial name and surname like `query="Nam Sur"` but i don't have any return instance in DB and I exactly have this user wit `name="Name" surname="Surname"`
It's my BinaryExpression into filter.

```
search = and_(
    (Doctor.name.ilike(f"%{query}%") | Doctor.surname.ilike(f"%{query}%"))
    | (
        (Doctor.name + " " + Doctor.surname).ilike(f"%{query}%")
        | (Doctor.surname + " " + Doctor.name).ilike(f"%{query}%")
    )
    | ((Doctor.name + Doctor.surname).ilike(f"%{query}%") | (Doctor.surname + Doctor.name).ilike(f"%{query}%"))
)
```

How I can implement my case ?

Comment: Replace any spaces with `%` in your input string if you want to match any subqueries; however, be aware that any LIKE matches like this will need to search the whole table - which might not be a problem, depending on the number of rows in your table. Alternatives are usually something like full text search with wildcards; how that's implemented and what's available will depend on which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: When I want to search by partial name and surname FE `query="Nam Sur"` and have instacne with `name="Name"` `surname="Surname"`

Comment: Try to formulate how you want the search to work, and then write the code. `query = "Nam Sur"` doesn't match any of the queries you've listed. One example could be "split the query string on space, and check if any part of it is contained in either `name` or `surname`"